# sass gem permission denied error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, twitter-bootstrap

Since I tried installing bootstrap-sass gem in my existing project I am getting this kind of error:

```
A Errno::EACCES occurred in #:

 Permission denied - /app/public/stylesheets/application.css.css
 .bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.15/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:355:in `initialize'
```

When I refresh the page, it seems to work again.

It also seems to happen with another of my css files which by way, I am not using at all.
my CSS.SCSS files are in the assets folder.

```
A Errno::EACCES occurred in #:

 Permission denied -/app/public/stylesheets/anaerobic_digestion_kinetics_calculator.css.css
```

.bundle/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.1.15/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:355:in `initialize'

Both these files were added when attempting to configure bootstrap-sass

Any idea why this is happening and if I could just delete them?

hope you can help,

joel

Comment: first of all it looks like your files should be named `*.css.scss` instead of `*.css.css`

Comment: and one of the libraries seems to be trying to access your app from root `/app/public` instead of a relative path `app/public`
could you show your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`?

Comment: these files are automatically generated. I deleted them and yet they were created again ??

Answer (score 0):

This helped : http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-sass

Looks like the gem is trying to write on heroku environment stack.